# Cosa significa 'o anche' in 'Questa questione è superabile al verificarsi della condizione X o anche al verificarsi della condizione Y'?

Tags: grammar

> Questa questione è superabile al verificarsi della condizione X o anche al verificarsi della condizione Y.

Cosa significa la frase testé trascritta?

1. Che la questione è superabile al verificarsi della sola condinzione X.
2. Che la questione è superabile al verificarsi della sola condinzione Y.
3. Che la questione è superabile al verificarsi di entrambe le condizioni X e Y.

Ci fosse solo "***o***" sarebbe chiaro, ma la locuzione "***o anche***", cioé la 'o' seguita da 'anche', non mi consente di capire.

Answer (score 6):

*Questa questione* is really ugly. `;-)`.

The meaning is clear: either condition X or condition Y is sufficient.

The way the sentence is built may induce the idea that condition X is the most probable; but it's clear from *anche* that the *o* is not to be intended in exclusive sense.

If it had been *e anche*, then interpretation 3 would be the only acceptable one. Many people (wrongly) feel that *o* only means the Latin *aut*; but it's undoubtedly usable and used in the sense of *vel*. So in many cases people resort to *o anche* or even to the horrible *e/o*.

Comment: Aggiungo che "o anche" è presente piuttosto spesso nell'uso corrente della lingua italiana, il mio parere è che "anche" venga aggiunto come rafforzativo al generico "o", quindi la condizione X oppure la condizione Y oppure ENTRAMBE le condizioni.

Comment: Si potrebbe dire l'equivalente logico di un "or non esclusivo"

Answer (score 1):

La frase è ambigua in modo irresolubile. Il chiarimento che chiedi riguarda lo statuto di verità della proposizione complessiva in funzione della verità delle due proposizioni costituenti. Se ci fosse solo "o" non sarebbe comunque risolta in quanto la disgiunzione italiana "o" non distingue tra aut (o esclusivo) e vel (non esclusivo) propri dell'uso latino (come giustamente messo in luce da @egreg). Il termine "anche" non è un connettivo logico bensì una particella copulativa che accresce quanto si è già detto; ovvero, in questo contesto, indica l'aggiunta di un'altra condizione ma non è dirimente in quanto non chiarisce la natura della connessione logica postulata.